# What are the difference between .bin and .pt pytorch saved model types?

Tags: pytorch

Sometimes I see .bin files for pretrained pytorch, like the one here

https://github.com/allenai/scibert#pytorch-models

However, the files are usually saved as .pt files.

What's the difference between these two parameter weights file formats? Why are there two?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

There is no difference as it's just an extension. When it comes to UNIX-like OSes one can open the file no matter the extension (see [here](https://www.quora.com/Why-is-there-no-extension-in-Linux)), Windows on the other hand is built with them in mind ([here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/803434/do-file-extensions-have-any-purpose-for-the-operating-system)).

`torch` can read either `.bin` or `.pt` or `.anything` so it's probably convention employed by the creators of that repository.

Standard approach is to use `.pt` or `.pth`, though the second extension collides with Python's text file readable by interpreter, so `.pt` seems to be the best idea for now (see [this github issue](https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/issues/14864)).

Comment: your github link is not forwarding to github but askubuntu :)

Comment: If they are identical in format, then I'd strongly recommend creators choose a semantically *meaningful* filename extension, for the user's benefit and program association. `.bin` is a generic extension that could many anything under the sun and has been used by countless programs to mean different things.

Looking at two such files on my local drive, OpenAI CLIP "pytorch_model.bin" and "RealESRGAN_x4plus.pth", I saw they have different headers. The `.bin` file is actually a `.zip` file (it has a "PK" header), and the `.pth` is a Python Pickle.

Comment: @DwayneRobinson does that mean the chosen answer is actually wrong?

Comment: @JohnJiang: I can't say without a larger corpus of files to compare, as there may be other `.bin` files which are pure Python pickles (not wrapped inside a `.zip` container), but looking inside the zip (just rename `.bin` to `.zip`), I see an `archive\data.pkl` pickle file, but the weights are stored separately under the `data\` folder as numbered files. So, either way, the model is a Python pickle file, but maybe the weights are stored embedded in one case and loose in the other.